# react-native: error when run project on macos mojave

Tags: ios, macos, react-native

I got the error when run the project.
Please help me resolve it. Thank you so much.

### Info:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szzYR.png)

### Error:

> Error: info Found Xcode workspace "StillError.xcworkspace" info
> Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace StillError.xcworkspace
> -configuration Debug -scheme StillError -destination id=26886618-C6CF-463F-9A5F-A23B77E20B00") error Failed to build iOS
> project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65.
> To debug build logs further, consider building your app with
> Xcode.app, by opening StillError.xcworkspace. note: Using new build
> system note: Planning build note: Using build description from disk
> warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this
> target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are
> configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target
> 'OpenSSL-Universal' from project 'Podenter code heres') PhaseScriptExecution [CP]
> Copy\ XCFrameworks
> ......
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy
> XCFrameworks
> /Users/_tupt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StillError-bxukiiaafgsohdhalcesljnliurj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenSSL-Universal.build/Script-329FE3CB18B30DBF34BE47031BE8F397.sh
> (1 failure)
>
> info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error upgrading my macOS to Big Sur and Xcode to 12.5